# How can I fix the 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load' error in Yandex Metrica's Session Replay feature?

Tags: yandex-metrika

I'm hosted in wpmudev.com with nginx server and i'm using wordpress with Impreza Theme installed. I have all the plugins from wpmudev installed and configured.

When viewing the console with "mywebsite.com/?_ym_debug=1"i get this error.

[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://mc.yandex.ru/webvisor/93823622?wv-check=3341&wv-type=0&wmode=0&wv-part=9&wv-hit=73998902&page... due to access control checks.
(anonymous function) (watch.js:87:317)
Promise
he (watch.js:176:464)
Ln (watch.js:87:82)
Ln
Hi (watch.js:111:462)
(anonymous function) (watch.js:111:106)
(anonymous function) (watch.js:110:485)

The tag is installed correctly and i tried Yandex Metrica 1.0 and 2.0B.

Don't know what else to try.

Any help?